# How to Connect GATT Server in Xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, bluetooth-gatt

In Xamarin Forms,

I want to know how the GATT server works with BLE for iOS.

Anyone can help how to connect GATT server with iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do think that it's a big question. You could refer to [*Bluetooth GATT Xamarin.Forms client*](https://www.jenx.si/2019/08/16/bluetooth-gatt-xamarin-forms-client/) and its related [*xamarin project*](https://github.com/josipx/Jenx.Bluetooth.GattServer). Generally, several steps should be taken

1. check the bluetooth-le status
2. scan the GATT server
3. connect the server
4. Get Service
5. Get Characteristic

According to the [*implementation and complete understanding of BLE(Bluetooth low energy) in Xamarin forms*](https://judsonabraham301.medium.com/implementation-and-complete-understanding-of-ble-bluetooth-low-energy-in-xamarin-forms-86de64144dc)  you should also add some keys and values in your info.plist

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>bluetooth-central</string>
        <string>bluetooth-peripheral</string>
    </array>
<key>NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription</key>
<string>YOUR CUSTOM MESSAGE</string>
<key>NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>YOUR CUSTOM MESSAGE</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>YOUR CUSTOM MESSAGE</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>YOUR CUSTOM MESSAGE</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>YOUR CUSTOM MESSAGE</string>
```

Also, you could refer to [*Bluetooth LE plugin for Xamarin & MAUI*](https://github.com/dotnet-bluetooth-le/dotnet-bluetooth-le) which might be useful for understanding.

Comment: Is GAP Profile is BLE? do we need to do any native call to discover GAP profile devices in Xamarin forms ?